# Freeing memory for a three dimensional matrix

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm running into problems freeing up my allocated memory while doing image processing in C.  I'm loading my jpeg images from a file, and then perform certain manipulations depending on whether or not the image is in grayscale or RGB.

The point is that the vector where the data is loaded will have one of these two structures:

```
data { R, G, B, R, G, B, ... }
// OR
data { value, value, value }
```

This is how I defined my structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int bytes_per_pixel;    /* 3 COLOR o 1 ESCALA DEGRISES  */
    int color_space;  /* JCS_RGB; o JCS_GRAYSCALE */
    unsigned char *dat;     /* vector de datos de la imagen descomprimida*/
    unsigned char **im;  /* matriz de punteros para acceder a cada valor de la imagen */
    unsigned char *** imgRGB;   // [i][j][0] red, [i][j][1] green,[i][j][2] blue
} imagenJPG;
```

The `im` field is always allocated, while `imgRGB` is only allocated when the generated image is in RGB.  I do that with this code:

```
extern void  generar_imagen(imagenJPG *oimagen, int h, int w, int bytesxPixel, unsigned char val)
{
    int i, j;
    oimagen->width = w;
    oimagen->height = h;
    oimagen->bytes_per_pixel = bytesxPixel;
    if (bytesxPixel == 1)
        oimagen->color_space = JCS_GRAYSCALE;
    else
        oimagen->color_space = JCS_RGB;

    /* asignar memoria a la imagen*/

    if ((oimagen->dat = (unsigned char *) malloc(w*h * bytesxPixel * sizeof(unsigned char))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*crear punteros a los pixeles segun el numero de componentes:*/

    if ((oimagen->im = (unsigned char **) malloc(h * sizeof(unsigned char *))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < h; i++) 
        oimagen->im[i] = &oimagen->dat[i * w * bytesxPixel];

    /* inicializar los pixeles de la imagen*/
    memset(oimagen->dat, val, h * w);

    if (bytesxPixel == 3)
    {
        /* para imagenes RGB una matriz de 3 dimensiones*/

        if ((oimagen->imgRGB = malloc(h * sizeof(unsigned char **))) == NULL)            
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
            exit(1);
        }   

        for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            if ((oimagen->imgRGB[i] = malloc (w * sizeof(unsigned char *))) == NULL)            
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                if ((oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = malloc(3 * sizeof(unsigned char ))) == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
                    exit(1);
                }  

                oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = &oimagen->dat[i*w*3+3*j];
            }
        }


        /*   inicializar los pixeles de la imagen*/
        memset(oimagen->dat, val, h*w*3);
    }

}
```

This way I can access every pixel of the image in a two dimensional way for greyscale, and use the third dimension for RGB.  The problem comes when I try to free the image. This is what I tried: (among with many other combinations)

```
void  liberar_imagen(imagenJPG iimagen)
{        
    free(iimagen.dat);
    free(iimagen.im);

    if (iimagen.bytes_per_pixel==3)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < iimagen.height; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < iimagen.width; j++) {
                free(iimagen.imgRGB[i][j]);
            }
            free(iimagen.imgRGB[i]);
        }
        free(iimagen.imgRGB);
    }
}
```

I always end up with either a seg fault or a double-free corruption. The only way I can make the program work is with this function:

```
void  liberar_imagen(imagenJPG iimagen)
{

    free(iimagen.dat);
    free(iimagen.im);

    if (iimagen.bytes_per_pixel == 3)
    {            
        free(iimagen.imgRGB);
    }

}
```

But this unfortunately doesn't free all of the memory - what should I do?

EDIT:   well, this is how I have it now and it works like a charm.But, is this the proper way to do it?: (notice that I only commented the allocation).

```
 for (j=0;j<w;j++){

               /* if ((oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] =malloc (3* sizeof(unsigned char )))== NULL )
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
                    exit(1);
                }*/  

                oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = &oimagen->dat[i*w*3+3*j];
            }
```

And the function for freeing the memory:

```
void  liberar_imagen(imagenJPG iimagen)
{
    int i;
    free(iimagen.dat);
    free(iimagen.im);

    if (iimagen.bytes_per_pixel==3)
    {
        for (i=0;i<iimagen.height;i++)
        free(iimagen.imgRGB[i]);
    }

            free(iimagen.imgRGB);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            // *** an array of 3 chars is allocated
            if ((oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = malloc(3 * sizeof(unsigned char ))) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Funcion generar_imagen: malloc error\n");
                exit(1);
            }  
            // *** the pointer to the 3-char array is overwritten with a pointer to dat
            oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = &oimagen->dat[i*w*3+3*j];
        }
```

When the memory malloc'ed is overwritten, it causes a memory leak.  Then you try to free the memory at each `oimagen->imgRGB[i][j]`, which is not at the beginning of a malloc'ed block.  This causes undefined behavior, which in your case manifests in a core dump.

This can be fixed by simply not allocating any memory in this block, and subsequently not attempting to `free` it.

So the above loop will now look like this:

```
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            oimagen->imgRGB[i][j] = &oimagen->dat[i*w*3+3*j];
        }
```

And your cleanup function would look like this:

```
void  liberar_imagen(imagenJPG iimagen)
{        
    free(iimagen.dat);
    free(iimagen.im);

    if (iimagen.bytes_per_pixel==3)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < iimagen.height; i++) {
            free(iimagen.imgRGB[i]);
        }
        free(iimagen.imgRGB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, i actually did not need to allocate that memory.

Comment: @Dannnno Edited. Had to step away before I could add more detail.

Comment: @dbush,  Thank you, i did reach the solution before you edited but now I understand better the reasons.